# How to retrieve deleted/overwitten v4.master and default.master in sharepoint designer 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, master-page

I accidentally deleted v4.master and overwrote my default.master in sharepoint 2013 designer.

Is there any way to retrieve these lost files? Can I download `default.master` anywhere to get back that copy?

Please help thank you.

Comment: If the below solution for retrieving the item from your recycle bin isn't available for any reason (e.g. recycle bin disabled), your best bet would be to rely on backups you hopefully have configured for your environment. Also when files are overwritten, their (hopefully existing) file version history is the easiest way to return the file to its original state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the deleted items like the master page from the `Site Recycle Bin` as the following:

- Site Setting > Site Collection Administration > Recycle Bin

[image]

- Or navigate to `sitecoll/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx`
- Just select your deleted master page, and then click restore!

[image]